# What is environment for an interpreter?

Tags: scheme, interpreter

I'm taking a course named *Programming Language Principles*. It introduces design of a simple interpreter.

And gere's one piece code of this interpreter:

```
(define valof
 (lambda (exp env)
  (dmatch exp
    [,sym (guard (symbol? sym)) (env sym)]
    ... )))
```

I want to know what is environment in an interpreter.

Comment: what do you mean by "environment" ?

Comment: For a lot of interpreters their environment is a little booth with a microphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an interpreter like the one you're looking at, the environment is the object that associates values with variable names.  Typically it is a list of frames, and each frame is a list of variable bindings.

Take a look at [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%_sec_3.2) for a discussion of how an evaluator uses an environment.