# What's the difference between an environment and a frame in computer science?

Tags: computer-science, environment, interpreter, evaluate

I'm reading a section of a textbook on interpreters and evaluation and I can't seem to find a distinct difference between the definition of an environment and that of a frame.

The textbook seems to differentiate between the two (although they are used in seemingly the same way, at times), however, so I'm wondering what the difference may be.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336141/what-is-environment-for-an-interpreter

Comment: Thanks, but the answer to that question isn't much more detailed than that of my textbook. Both an environment and a frame seem to have something to do with name-value bindings, but I'm not clear on what makes the two different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there. Here is the documentation from the UCB CS61A, hope this may help you.

> An frame is a box that contains bindings from variables to values. An frame can “extend” another frame; that is,
> this frame can see all bindings of the frame it extends. We represent this by drawing an arrow from an
> environment frame to the frame it is extending. The global environment is the only environment that extends
> nothing.
>
> An environment is a series of frames, which we get from extending the current frame. To determine which
> frames are in an environment, follow the arrows until reaching the global environment. Every frame you passed
> through is part of that environment. The global environment is only made up of the global frame, because its
> frame extends nothing.

Here is the link:
[https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp12/discussion/week2/week2_notes_sol.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/sp12/discussion/week2/week2_notes_sol.pdf)